# What is a practical level of abstraction in a web application?

Tags: php, design-patterns, object-oriented, web-applications, validation

(Originally asked on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896121/what-is-a-practical-level-of-abstraction-in-a-web-application)

I still consider myself a newcomer to OO programming, especially in php, so forgive me if I have missed some fundamental principle!

Say I have an intranet application with a `staff` object with properties and methods unique to being a member of staff:

```
class staff {
    ...
    private $job_title;
    private $start_date;
    etc...
}
```

In the quest to keep the maintainable parts of my code in one place, make my data model more intelligent and make my code less tightly-coupled, is it reasonable to abstract each object property to another level?

For example, I expect each property to have a `value`, but to complicate matters, I'm also interested in what `label` and `description` to use when referring to it in human-readable applications. More of interest is which `type` it is, as well as the capability of the object to validate itself, if its member properties can validate themselves also. It seems then, that properties of the majority of objects have a lot in common. So, the `$start_date` property might actually be an object in itself:

```
abstract class property {
    public $value = NULL;
    protected $label; // A simple label which can be used on user forms, reports, etc.
    protected $description; // Some detail to describe what this property is used for
    protected $type; // Helps choose the right HTML form control and validate user input
    protected $regex; // Regular expression to prompt user entry and validate return value
    protected $unique = FALSE; // If TRUE, check for duplicates in the persistence layer
    protected $default_value; // Prompt the user when entering new values
    protected $HTML_form_element; // Which form element suits this field best?
    etc....
}

class start_date extends property {
    ...
    public function __construct(){
        ...
        $this->label = 'Start date'; // Might be an i18n entry
        $this->description = 'Enter the date on which the contract starts for this staff member'; // Might be an i18n entry
        $this->type = 'VARCHAR(512)'; // Better to use persistence layer's requirements?
        $this->regex = '/^([0-9]{1,2})[/.-]([0-9]{1,2})[/.-]([0-9]{2,4})$/'; // UK date
        $this->default_value = date('Y-m-d'); // Depends on the business policy of the company
        $this->HTML_form_element= 'datepicker'; // Chooses the correct HTML element when building forms automatically
        ...
    }
    etc...
}

class staff {
    ...
    public function __construct(){
        ...
        $start_date = new start_date();
        ...
    }
    etc...
}
```

In previous applications, these related things have lived in different places; random global variables, commented code, decorator objects, a config file, embeded in HTML, a database table, a scrap of paper. It makes sense to bring all an objects properties together in one place, but is this the right way?

Answer (score 4):

The data you are describing is *meta* data. Many languages have clean ways to store this information, such as **annotations**. [The PHP team as rejected native annotations](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/annotations) time and time again, but Symfony2 and Doctrine2 have a home-grown implementation using doc-block comments. *This is far from the ideal solution*, but it's the best work around we have at the moment. This is the same way annotations were created in Java *before* native annotations were implemented by Sun in Java 5.

I'm not sure if the Symfony/Doctrine solution is available as a stand alone component or not. I think Symfony relies on the doctrine-common library to parse annotations.

Either way, check out [Symfony2 Form Vaidation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation)

```
// Acme/TaskBundle/Entity/Task.php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Task
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $task;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
     */
    protected $dueDate;
}
```

The information you're trying to describe with a *has-a* relationship above is cleanly described here without muddying up the code. Internally, these comments are parsed and cached in pure PHP so they can be looked up at run-time.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but can you elaborate on why the PHP team rejected annotations?

Comment: From what I can tell, it's mostly been that they don't accept the purposed implementation. I think syntax has been the biggest factor.

Comment: Found this a while back: http://interfacelab.com/metadataattributes-in-php/